# Memory Leak using Thread Local Storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, windbg, thread-local-storage

After a few days, our web site clearly suffer from a memory leak (> 2Gb /pool). So, I ran a few commands on windbg and finally found something : there are many `System.LocalDataStoreElement`. After a quick search in the source code (see below), I found a really stange class :

```
public class HomeController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        CultureInfoManager.SetCulture(MyCompany.Internal.Enumerations.Site.GbEn);
    }
}
public class CultureInfoManager
{
    [ThreadStaticAttribute]
    private static Language _language;

    public static void SetCulture(Site site)
    {
        if (site == Site.Undefined) return;

        //strange ???
        var localSlot = Thread.AllocateDataSlot();
        Thread.SetData(localSlot, site.Code());

        _language = site.GetLanguage();

        var cultureInfo = CreateCultureInfo(site);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }

    private static CultureInfo CreateCultureInfo(Site site)
    {
        if (site == Site.Undefined) site = Site.GbEn;
        var languageCode = site.GetLanguage().Code();
        switch (languageCode)
        {
            case "f2":
                return new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            case "br":
                return new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
            case "s1":
                return new CultureInfo("es-AR");
            case "s2":
                return new CultureInfo("es-CL");
            case "e1":
                return new CultureInfo("en-CA");
            default:
                return new CultureInfo(languageCode);
        }
    }

    public static Language GetCurrentLanguage()
    {
        return _language;
    }

}
```

So, my questions :

- Using Thread.AllocateDataSlot is clearly useless here, but can it explain the memory leak ? Because after a complete load test (more than 400 000 requests), I can not reproduce the leak.
- Is it pertinent to use TLS/ThreaStatic for web applications ? because in asp.net, we  you don't control the thread life and a because the worker thread will execute many requests.

I also found an issue in MS KB [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2540745).

In conclusion, everything seems to be on this piece of code, but I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: **Never**, and I repeat, **absolutely never** use `ThreadStatic` in an ASP.NET application. I see tat you are doing some sort of localization here. I would use a route parameter for this. It's much better in terms of SEO. And then you could have a global action attribute that will read this route parameter and set the current thread culture so that it is available for the entire request.

Comment: thanks, for the "Never, Never, Never" but could you please explain me why ? and what about Thread.AllocateDataSlot?

Comment: Because there's absolutely nothing guaranteeing you that each request is served by a different thread. As you know ASP.NET uses a thread pool to service requests. By using the `ThreadStatic` attribute you are basically tying the lifetime of your object to the **Thread**, not to the **Request**. Even worse you could have 2 completely different requests served by exactly the same thread from ASP.NET meaning that you will get a very bad data mixture between your users. And things are even more complicated that that. For example if you use asynchronous controllers you could have ... (continue)

Comment: ... the same request be served by 2 **different** threads. You could start the request on one thread and finish it on the other. By tying your variables to the thread you are completely mixing your object lifetimes.